# Google Mobile Ads (AdMob) - no ads being shown

Tags: java, android, admob, google-play-services, ads

My code looks exactly like the original (https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals?hl=en#play) and I'm sure I imported everything correctly, added meta-data, activity and permissions to my AndroidManifest.

When I'm starting the application on my device logcat gives me the following:

```
03-23 10:18:45.874: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(12473): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
03-23 10:18:45.974: D/WebView(12473): onSizeChanged - w:960 h:150
03-23 10:18:46.094: W/ActivityThread(12473): ClassLoader.loadClass: The class loader returned by Thread.getContextClassLoader() may fail for processes that host multiple applications. You should explicitly specify a context class loader. For example: Thread.setContextClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
03-23 10:19:17.244: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(12473): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
03-23 10:19:17.265: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(12473): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
03-23 10:20:17.243: W/Ads(12473): Timed out waiting for ad response.
03-23 10:20:17.253: E/SQLiteLog(12473): (14) cannot open file at line 32512 of [00bb9c9ce4]
03-23 10:20:17.253: I/Ads(12473): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
03-23 10:20:17.263: W/Ads(12473): Failed to load ad: 2
```

This Google Play service resources not found and Failed to load ad error are repeating every minute.

My UnitId is correct and my TestDevice-Id as well.

Comment: I even downloaded the sample here https://google-mobile-dev.googlecode.com/files/BannerExample_Play_1.0.zip?hl=en and have the same problem -> Failed to load ad

Comment: Do you have included the Google Play Services library to your project?

Comment: Yes of course I did, otherwise eclipse wouldn't let me debug it on the device.

Answer (score 0):

I think the toast message with that is "failed to load (invalid request)" probably because you have not updated the string INSERT_YOUR_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE with a real ad unit id, which you have to get by signing up for an account with AdMob or another provider of ads and requesting an id for your app.